# Does the level of your lead Pokémon affect what Pokémon you encounter?

Tags: pokemon-black-white

On Pokémon White, when I was first in the Desert Resort, I encountered mainly Sandile and Darumaka.  However, after training up my lead Pokémon, a Servine, from about level 20 or so to about level 30, I noticed that I was encountering many more Maracti and Sigilyph, and hardly any Sandile or Darumaka.  When I first started training in the location, I rarely encountered Maracti or Sigilph, but at one point, when the level of my lead Pokémon was higher, I encountered six Maracti in a row, along with many Sigiliphs.  Did my luck just take a turn for the better, or is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time your lead Pokemon has any effect to the Pokemon that appear in the wild, is if they have an ability that does so. Such as Pikachu with the **Static** ability. With him as your lead Pokemon, you have a higher chance to draw in Electric type Pokemon if they spawn in that area.

The level of your lead Pokemon would not have this type of effect, it's all RNG when it comes to encounters. So it was just coincidence that you started encountering different Pokemon after you leveled up Servine.

**EDIT:** If you were using a Repel, and the Pokemon you were encountering were HIGHER than level 30, then yes your lead Pokemon *could* effect what Spawns. If the other Pokemon you were encountering only spawn below level 30 and a repel is used, that could change what you encounter.

Comment: The first sentence isn't fully accurate. The party leader's level affects Pokemon spawns while using [repel](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Repel) :)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning Intimidate, Keen Eye, Hustle, Vital Spirit, and Pressure.

Comment: Here's a full list of abilities that affect encounters: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Abilities_that_affect_appearance_of_wild_Pok%C3%A9mon. Of note, Cute Charm makes opposing Pokemon more likely to be the opposite gender of your lead Pokemon - so that ability also depends on your lead's gender.

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes when using Repel, I forgot about that. I guess if those other rarer spawns were higher than level 30 (like the OP's example) and the other Pokemon were lower than 30, then yes, it would have that effect of what spawns.